# populating depended spinner from independent spinner listener

Tags: android, spinner, listener, android-spinner

i have spinner1 with `OnItemSelectedListener` that should update values in adapter of `spinner2` when `onItemSelected` accurs.
when i trying to get `spinner2` by id from the activity that  implements `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` i get a null pointer exception on:

```
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

Is there a standart resolution for working with two spinners?